# Is this the issue of not logging in as root?

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, root, pry

As far as i remember while installing ubuntu,the installer didn't ask me for the root password. It asked me to create an account just before preparing for the first time use.There i specified a username and a password.I use this password to log onto my ubuntu machine. I had to install something which gave the following error :

[image]

What could be the problem ? when i enter as root an mention the password,it says `auth failure`. How

Comment: Wrong place to ask. http://askubuntu.com/ is a better place. And you should use `sudo`

Comment: sudo -s would switch you to root then you can continue from there (you need to type your password in the prompt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps better suited on SuperUser...

Text taken from [ubuntu-help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

By default, the Root account password is locked in Ubuntu. This means that you cannot login as Root directly or use the su command to become the Root user. However, since the Root account physically exists it is still possible to run programs with root-level privileges. This is where sudo comes in - it allows authorized users (normally "Administrative" users; for further information please refer to AddUsersHowto) to run certain programs as Root without having to know the root password.

This means that in the terminal you should use sudo for commands that require root privileges

So, in your case, use `sudo gem install` instead

Answer (score 0):

yes. This is a root problem.

What command did you try for going root?

Did you just type `su <username>`

Type in `sudo su`

Then use the username/password combo to get into root.

The gem will work then.